# Motivation for $p$-stabilization in Hida theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, hida-theory

I'm currently reading [Hida's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01388661) "A $p$-adic measure attached to the zeta functions associated with two elliptic modular forms". The setup is the following: let $f$ be a weight $2$ newform for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(N)$. Let $p$ be a good ordinary prime. Let $\alpha, \beta$ be the eigenvalues of Frobenius where $\alpha$ is a $p$-adic unit. Two questions:

1. Hida considers the $\alpha$-stabilization of $f$ which is defined as

$$f_{\alpha}(z) = f(z) - \beta f(pz).$$

**Question:** Why do we work with the form $f_{\alpha}$ instead of the form $f$ directly? What is the motivation behind the definition of $f_{\alpha}$?

2. Hida defined the projector operator $L_{f_{\alpha}}$ such that for any $g \in \Gamma_0(Np^r)$:
   $$L_{f_{\alpha}}(g) = \alpha^{1-r} \dfrac{ \langle \overline{f_{\alpha}} \vert_2 W_{Np^r}, g \rangle_{Np^r}}{ \langle \overline{f_{\alpha}} \vert_2 W_{Np}, f_{\alpha} \rangle_{Np}}, $$
   where $f \vert_2 \gamma$ is the slash operator by the matrix $\gamma$ and $W_M$ is the matrix of the Fricke involution:

$$ W_M = [0 -1; M, 0] $$

**Question:** What is the motivation behind the definition of this operator $L_{f_{\alpha}}$? Is this the projection onto the $f_{\alpha}$ subspace? And if so, why does this operator take this weird form involving Fricke involutions?

Comment: For 1: $f$ is probably a newform of level $N$, so its degeneracies to level $Np$ won't be $U_p$-eigenvectors. The $p$-stabilization is, however.